# Parsing ISO8601 date string with DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, iso8601

I'm trying to parse an ISO8601 format string as follows:

```
"2013-07-16T13:40:20+01:00"
```

It represents a GMT time adjusted for daylight savings (BST). When I parse this however the `DateTime.ParseExact` behavior isn't what I expected:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("2013-07-16T13:40:20-02:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", null));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("2013-07-16T13:40:20-01:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", null));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("2013-07-16T13:40:20+00:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", null));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("2013-07-16T13:40:20+01:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", null));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("2013-07-16T13:40:20+02:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", null));
```

Produces output of:

```
16/07/2013 16:40:20
16/07/2013 15:40:20
16/07/2013 14:40:20
16/07/2013 13:40:20
16/07/2013 12:40:20
```

Is there a way to get the parse method to interpret the string as a BST time?

Thanks.

Comment: [DateTime Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx): _"An alternative to the DateTime structure for working with date and time values in particular time zones is the DateTimeOffset structure. The DateTimeOffset structure stores date and time information in a private DateTime field and the number of minutes by which that date and time differs from UTC in a private Int16 field. This makes it possible for a DateTimeOffset value to reflect the time in a particular time zone, whereas a DateTime value can unambiguously reflect only UTC and the local time zone's time."_

Comment: That is an offset.  Suspect it is printing local time.   If you want UTC then use ToUniversalTime();